# Angular UI-Router with dynamic URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I had my code working with `ngRoute` with no problems to load files by dynamic generate a URL for my views files:

```
.when('/page/:name*', {
        templateUrl: function(urlattr){
            return '/views/' + urlattr.name + '.view.html';
        },
        controller: 'PageController'
})
```

but then I got to move to UI Router in order to use nested views, but what is the equivalent of the above code with UI Router? I've tried the following code:

```
.state('home.pages', {
        url: "/page/:name*",
        controller: 'PageController',
        templateUrl: function(urlattr){
            return '/views/' + urlattr.name + '.view.html';
        }
});
```

and I'm getting the error

```
Could not resolve '/page/test' from state 'home'
```

In my anchor I'm trying to call it by the URL. The link comes from a database that knows URLs but not state names

```
<!-- I want to load '/views/test.view.html' file -->;
<a href="#/page/test">Link not working</a>
<div ui-view>nested view content</div>
```

Comment: do you have a parent state `home`? You are showing `home.pages` which would be child state of `home`

Comment: Yes I do. And it's working fine

Comment: Where is the urlattr being passed in? I dont see query strings on the url.

Comment: it's not a query string. I want to take the substring after `page/` from the URL. Example 'test.view.html'

Comment: Ok, just try removing *

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are creating your anchor incorrectly. You should be doing something like

```
<a ui-sref="home.pages({param: value})">Link</a>
```

Comment: that won't pass the url param though

Comment: I edited to allow passing params. If that is not what you mean, can you show your markup?

Comment: Is that a what to pass the URL instead of the state name? The link comes from a database that knows URLs but not state names

Comment: Yes, the normal way <a href="/page/test?param=value">Link</a> works. That is why I wanted to see what you were doing.